# How many beings has Boba Fett killed since escaping from the Sarlacc?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett, kill-count, the-book-of-boba-fett

Critics of *The Book of Boba Fett* keep calling Boba *soft*, but since escaping from the Sarlacc, he's killed quite a few beings. He killed the 4-armed sand monster, and at least 20 Pykes. In addition, in *The Mandalorian: Season 2*, he killed at least 10 Stormtroopers. He's also killed all kind of beings who have attacked him on the streets of Mos Espa, and of course, he killed Bib Fortuna and Cad Bane. So, the idea that Boba Fett is *soft*, is inaccurate. My ball park figure is 50 confirmed kills for Boba post-Sarlacc from 4 ABY to 9 ABY -- so far.

Comment: https://listofdeaths.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett

Comment: I guess they're having him kill lots of people to make up for the fact that he got his butt whooped by a blind guy with a stick.

Comment: This seems to be a question where every given answer would become obsolete with every new episode of the Mandalorian. Voting to close as about future works.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. The first season is complete, an answer can be given at least for that, considering we don't know when/if a second season is coming.

Comment: There is no reason to close this.   Answers can be updated as new information comes to light.   That is business as usual.   Otherwise we could almost never ask questions about ongoing properties.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not at all a given that Fett will even appear more.   It does, of course, look quite likely given the current state of the Filoni/Favreau Mando-verse, but c'mon guys, there's not even any announcement that indicates there will be more appearences of Fett.   Even those who think this is, in fact, a question that runs afoul the future works policy (it doesn't) don't have a leg to stand on.

Comment: Agreed with @ThePopMachine, if this question is closed for future works, every question about the recommended viewing order for ongoing series should be closed too.